# Setting up Jest to test JSX files

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsx, babeljs, babel-jest

If anyone has experience setting up Jest to test a React application, I would be eternally grateful for some help. I'm trying to set up Jest to test a simple JSX file, but I keep getting the following error. It seems like a simple thing to set up, but I have followed every official guide from the Babel, Jest, and babel-jest docs, and well as all the StackOverflow posts I could find, and the issue still persists.

- My app uses Babel and Webpack to transpile JSX files to JS.
- Jest works fine when testing regular .js files.
- I have both a babel.config.js and a .babelrc file (listed below), after trying to follow a bunch of solution threads.
- I'm running Ubuntu on WSL2.

```
    > jest --coverage

    (node:4689) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

    PASS  database/index.test.js
    FAIL  client/index.test.js
    ● Test suite failed to run                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    Jest encountered an unexpected token
    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
    Here's what you can do:
    • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
    • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
    • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:
    SyntaxError: /home/jsim0809/client/index.jsx: Unexpected token (5:16)
      3 | import QA from './components/QA';
      4 |
    > 5 | ReactDOM.render(<QA />, document.getElementById('q-a'));
        |                 ^
      6 |
      7 | export default ReactDOM.render;
      8 |
```

Here is what my repo looks like:

```js
// package.json

{
  "name": "",
  "version": "",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.13.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "start-dev": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "build-dev": "webpack --watch",
    "seed": "node database/seedDB.js",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "jestinit": "jest --init",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>testing/setupTests.js",
      "jest-enzyme"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "enzyme"
  }
}
```

```js
// client/index.jsx

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import QA from './components/QA';

ReactDOM.render(<QA />, document.getElementById('q-a'));

export default ReactDOM.render;
```

```js
// client/index.test.js

import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import ReactDOMRender from './index';


test('checks that the overall render method was called.', () => {
  expect(ReactDOMRender).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

```html
// public/index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="q-a">This will disappear when the React component loads.</div>
  </body>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

```js
// babel.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
  ],
};
```

```js
// .babelrc

{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

```js
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
  },
};
```

```js
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'index.jsx'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
};
```

Would really appreciate any pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
  },
};
```

The jest config is only transforming/transpiling .js files.

The regex in transform: '^.+\.js$'
will not match .jsx files.

Try '^.+\.jsx?$' and it will probably work. This will tell jest to transpile both .js and .jsx with babel-jest.